# Parse json Data in iOS

Tags: ios, json, api, parsing

I know it's a common question, but I am stuck with is API

How to Parse data from this API : http://dl.bahramradan.com/api/1/get/ig

it contain 20 Object and in every object there are 3 other Objects called "image",date" and "caption"

how can I store all "date" values in an NSMUtableArray in ios?

I did this :

```
    NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://dl.bahramradan.com/api/1/get/ig"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
    NSData *json = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:json options:0 error:NULL];

    NSArray *dateArray = [dict objectForKey:@"date"];
```

But when I run my app, it crashs on the last line, what is wrong ?

Comment: Your JSON structure: an `NSArray` of `NSDictionary`.

Comment: http://jsonlint.com and think about the structure. Also, `"when I tun my app, it crash, what is wrong" is a **stereotypical** bad question. You provided no useful information as to what might even cause the crash. You will need to **use the debugger and attempt to resolve the error yourself.**

Comment: Have you debugged the content of the parsed dictionary?

Comment: @Thanh-NhonNGUYEN Yes, and I guess it can be cast as an NSArray safelym but in action, it crashes.

Comment: Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  It only takes 5-10 minutes.  (What you have is an "array" of "objects".)  Then understand that you're probably doomed if you try to modify an example to do your JSON parsing -- you need to actually understand the syntax and understand how it maps to iOS objects (array -> NSArray, object ->NSDictionary).  Next, always, while debugging, include an NSLog of the parsed JSON at each step, understanding that an NSArray dumps with surrounding `()` characters and an NSDictonary dumps with surrounding `{}` characters.

Comment: Oh, and never say "it crashes" without including the *full* exception message and stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not check, if your JSON is valid. But there is one obvious mistake in your code: If the JSON consists of 20 objects, I assume those being contained in an array, rather than in a dict!

So first thing to change is

```
NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:json options:0 error:NULL];
```

Then, you want to extract the 'date' values for all items and combine these in another array.
Easiest way to achieve that, is by using a KVC Collection Operator

```
NSArray *dateArray = [array valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfObjects.date"];
```

So, what '@unionOfObjects.date' does, is: going through all the objects in the array, look for each of their 'date' value and combine them in the returned array.
[Check out this excellent post about KVC Collection Operators!](http://nshipster.com/kvc-collection-operators/)

Comment: Thank you! I had a big problem understanding json syntax, that's because I used dict! :)